# Jquery code doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I really don't understand why this snippet works in all browsers but chrome :S

```
    $(".tab1, .tab2, .tab3").css({"height":newHeight}).getNiceScroll().resize();
```

http://radio.idev.ge

**EDIT**

This looks like a jquery bug with css() for chrome, I changed css() to animate() and it works fine now.

I'm gonna submit bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a jquery bug with css() for chrome, I changed css() to animate() and it works fine now.

I'm gonna submit bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Console.log error:

> ***Viewport argument value "device-w‌​idth" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored.***

Check your `META` for a `null`character at line 5 `...width=device-w‌*​idth...`

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,height=device-height,width=device-w‌​idth,user-scalable=no">`

*[edited to paste a screenshot]*
[image]

---

And please.. paste code here or in a fiddle file.. your link reference would be useless to others when you fix the problem.

Comment: I don't think meta tag has anything to do with jquery not resizing div.

Comment: no?.. and why you are using it?.. I don't see any `media query's` in your `CSS`... At least you tried?

Comment: Hi, yes I removed whitespace as you suggested. Btw, how did you see null character there? console didn't tell me... anyways, on my dev laptop: http://mac.idev.ge:800/mobile-radio/

Comment: screenshot added... I saw it in `Sources` TAB & in the Console

Comment: Thanks! p.s. I changed css() to animate() and it works now. Could be jquery-chrome-css bug.

Comment: That's not a "jQuery-Chrome" bug, your `css()` function perfectly works, but is never called on Chrome.

Comment: @zessx Mind explaining in detail? if its not a bug why its not called?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze The function exists, you can check it typing the code line you provided into Chrome console. If it exist, and can be called, I can guess there's something else in your code which prevent the function's call.

Comment: @zessx but it is strange, changing only css to animate fixed everything... and it only not worked in chrome. anyways, could be my function.